# Delphi TidTCPServer and TidTCPClient transferring a record

Tags: delphi, indy

I need help in understanding how to transfer a record through Indy TCP Server/Client. I have 2 programs, in I put client and in another server.
On client on a button I put connect : Client is TIdTCPClient

```
Client.Connect();
```

And at server  side I am adding a line to memo that client is connected , on ServerConnect event

```
Protocol.Lines.Add(TimeToStr(Time)+' connected ');
```

To send data from client I have a record, which I want to send :

```
Tmyrecord = record
IPStr: string[15];
end;
```

And I have a send button there :

```
procedure Tform1.ButtonSendClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
  MIRec: Tmyrecord;
 msRecInfo: TMemoryStream;
 begin
   MIRec.IPStr := '172.0.0.1';
   msRecInfo := TMemoryStream.Create;
   msRecInfo.Write(MIRec, SizeOf(MIRec));
    msRecInfo.Position := 0;
   Client.IOHandler.Write(msRecInfo);
 end;
```

At server side onexecute I have the following code , I have same tmyrecord declared at server side too :

```
 procedure TServerFrmMain.ServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
 var
  MIRec: Tmyrecord;
  msRecInfo: TMemoryStream;
 begin
 if  AContext.Connection.Connected then
  begin
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(10);
    if not AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
   begin
     msRecInfo:= TMemoryStream.Create;
       AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(msRecInfo);
     msRecInfo.Read(MIRec, sizeOf(msRecInfo));
    ShowMessage(MIRec.IPStr);
 end;
 end;
 end
```

I dont know why it is not working, why I cant show IP adress which I wrote from client side. 
I want to read a record (msRecInfo) on server side which I am sending from client side. I want to access my record elements, in this case I want to read IPSTR element of my record. When I press send button from a client side, application hangs, server part.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I am trying to send a record , msRecInfo , lets say which has IPSTR element. I want to send that record, and read it from server. I want to read IPSTR from my record at server side

Comment: Just a suggestion to clean up your question and make it clear that this is your one question.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, edited my question, I hope it is better now

Comment: Which version of Delphi / Indy by the way?

Comment: You say it doesn't work - what happens, and what were you *expecting* to happen?

Comment: My delphi's a bity rusty, but delphi strings are normally heap based...? Maybe try changing TMyRecord to Array[0..15] of char?

Comment: Jerry, Delphi version doesn't matter (the `IPStr` is declared as a `ShortString`, and those are `AnsiChars` regardless of Delphi verison). The Indy version would help, though.

Comment: I want to get IPSTR value at server side. I am trying to show on show message.  I am getting balnk Showmessage dialog

Comment: @Samir, Ah, so *something* is  getting to the other end. Set a breakpoint before showmessage and look at the received data (also, check the size of the stream read.

Comment: @Roddy: `string[15]` is not a Delphi heap-based `String`. It is a `ShortString`, which is essentially a fixed-length size-prefixed array.

Comment: @SamirMemmedov: You are getting a blank string on the server side because you are not reading the stream correctly to begin with, but even if you were, you are not setting the stream's `Position` back to 0 after reading the stream data, so there is nothing for `Read()` to return.

Comment: @SamirMemmedov: Also, TIdTCPServer is a multithreaded component but neither `Protocol.Lines.Add()` nor `ShowMessage()` are thread-safe, so you need to watch out for that as well.  Use Indy's `TIdSync` or `TIdNotify` class to interact with the UI safely.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are making a classic newbie mistake - you are expecting the default behaviors of the `TIdIOHandler.Write(TStream)` and `TIdIOHandler.ReadStream()` methods to match each other, but they actually do not.

The default parameter values of `TIdIOHandler.ReadStream()` tell it to expect an `Integer` or `Int64` (depending on the value of the `TIdIOHandler.LargeStream` property) to preceed the stream data to specify the length of the data.

However, the default parameter values of `TIdIOHandler.Write(TStream)` do not tell it to send any such `Integer/Int64` value.  Thus, your use of `TIdIOHandler.ReadStream()` reads the first few bytes of the record and interprets them as an `Integer/Int64` (which is `926036233` given the string value you are sending), and then waits for that many bytes to arrive, which never will so `TIdIOHandler.ReadStream()` does not exit (unless you set the `TIdIOHandler.ReadTimeout` property to a non-infinite value).

There are also some other minor bugs/typos in your code that uses the `TMemoryStream` objects outside of Indy.

Try this instead:

```
procedure Tform1.ButtonSendClick(Sender: TObject); 
var 
  MIRec: Tmyrecord; 
  msRecInfo: TMemoryStream; 
begin 
  MIRec.IPStr := '172.0.0.1'; 
  msRecInfo := TMemoryStream.Create; 
  try
    msRecInfo.Write(MIRec, SizeOf(MIRec)); 

    // writes the stream size then writes the stream data
    Client.IOHandler.Write(msRecInfo, 0, True);
  finally
    msRecInfo.Free;
  end;
end; 

procedure TServerFrmMain.ServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext); 
var 
  MIRec: Tmyrecord; 
  msRecInfo: TMemoryStream; 
begin 
  msRecInfo := TMemoryStream.Create; 
  try
    // reads the stream size then reads the stream data
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(msRecInfo, -1, False);

    msRecInfo.Position := 0;
    msRecInfo.Read(MIRec, SizeOf(MIRec)); 
    ...
  finally
    msRecInfo.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or this:

```
procedure Tform1.ButtonSendClick(Sender: TObject); 
var 
  MIRec: Tmyrecord; 
  msRecInfo: TMemoryStream; 
begin 
  MIRec.IPStr := '172.0.0.1'; 
  msRecInfo := TMemoryStream.Create; 
  try
    msRecInfo.Write(MIRec, SizeOf(MIRec)); 

    // does not write the stream size, just the stream data
    Client.IOHandler.Write(msRecInfo, 0, False); 
  finally
    msRecInfo.Free;
  end;
end; 

procedure TServerFrmMain.ServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext); 
var 
  MIRec: Tmyrecord; 
  msRecInfo: TMemoryStream; 
begin 
  msRecInfo := TMemoryStream.Create; 
  try
    // does not read the stream size, just the stream data
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(msRecInfo, SizeOf(MIRec), False); 

    msRecInfo.Position := 0;
    msRecInfo.Read(MIRec, SizeOf(MIRec)); 
    ...
  finally
    msRecInfo.Free;
  end; 
end;
```

Alternatively, you can send the record using `TIdBytes` instead of `TStream`:

```
procedure Tform1.ButtonSendClick(Sender: TObject); 
var 
  MIRec: Tmyrecord; 
  Buffer: TIdBytes;
begin 
  MIRec.IPStr := '172.0.0.1'; 
  Buffer := RawToBytes(MIRec, SizeOf(MIRec));
  Client.IOHandler.Write(Buffer); 
end; 

procedure TServerFrmMain.ServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext); 
var 
  MIRec: Tmyrecord; 
  Buffer: TIdBytes; 
begin 
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(Buffer, SizeOf(MIRec)); 
  BytesToRaw(Buffer, MIRec, SizeOf(MIRec));
  ...
end;
```